# How to avoid floating-point arithmetic in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, math, decimal, bigdecimal

Say I have two columns, A and B, which are of type `DECIMAL(9,2)`.

Now, say I run the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(A) / SUM(B)
```

My understanding is that this division won't be done through floating-point arithmetic as both columns are of the `DECIMAL` type. Is this correct?

Also, say I run the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(A) / SUM(B) * 100
```

How will the `100` affect the query? Will this somehow cause MySQL to do floating-point arithmetic? If so, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Please provide a situation where the results are different.  Is there a reason for avoiding float?  MySQL is rather good at always getting the "right" answer.

Comment: @RickJames  I'm doing calculations involving monetary amounts. In Java, I would use BigDecimals and in PHP, bcmath or a library like brick/math. I'm not sure what is the equivalent of those in MySQL. According to my readings and my tests, the queries I have outlined provide the "right" answers, but I would like to double-check with people who know MySQL more than I do.

Comment: I have long pondered the question, but alas, I don't have a definitive answer.  For simple things like dollars and cents with simple addition, all sums should be exact.  But when you need division or banking-approved rounding, I would be suspicious.

Comment: Cross that bridge if and when you come to it.

Comment: *My understanding is that this division won't be done through floating-point arithmetic as both columns are of the DECIMAL type. Is this correct?* (1) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b25650ca012615d0884e05063ed50631 (2) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-expressions.html (3) From the practice: without explicit CAST the result of the expression is rounded to the most precise operand decimal places amount but not less than 6.

Comment: I never understood why people use decimal for currency. Just use integer and calculate in cent. It’s so easy and avoid every problem about round

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How will the 100 affect the query? Will this somehow cause MySQL to do floating-point arithmetic? If so, how can I avoid it?

100 is an exact-value numeric literal, here we have decimal divided by decimal times decimal(integer) => result is still decimal(but with higher precision).

[Numeric Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/number-literals.html)

> Exact-value numeric literals have an integer part or fractional part, or both. They may be signed. Examples: 1, .2, 3.4, -5, -6.78, +9.10.
>
> Approximate-value numeric literals are represented in scientific notation with a mantissa and exponent. Either or both parts may be signed. Examples: 1.2E3, 1.2E-3, -1.2E3, -1.2E-3.
>
> Two numbers that look similar may be treated differently. For example, 2.34 is an exact-value (fixed-point) number, whereas 2.34E0 is an approximate-value (floating-point) number.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t(A DECIMAL(9,2), B DECIMAL(9,2));

CREATE TABLE r1 AS SELECT SUM(A) / SUM(B) AS result FROM t;

SELECT column_name, column_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'r1';
+--------------+---------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  |  COLUMN_TYPE  |
+--------------+---------------+
| result       | decimal(37,6) |
+--------------+---------------+

CREATE TABLE r2 AS SELECT SUM(A) / SUM(B) * 100 AS result FROM t;

SELECT column_name, column_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'r2';
+--------------+---------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  |  COLUMN_TYPE  |
+--------------+---------------+
| result       | decimal(40,6) |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Now using approximate value numeric literal `100E0`:

```
CREATE TABLE r3 AS SELECT SUM(A) / SUM(B) * 100E0 AS result FROM t;

SELECT column_name, column_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'r3';
+--------------+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  | COLUMN_TYPE |
+--------------+-------------+
| result       | double      |
+--------------+-------------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27bd916133f418a26b92d7edebcd2374)**

---

It is worth noting that some operations may look exactly the same but return different data types. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE r4 AS SELECT POWER(A,2) AS result, A*A AS result2 FROM t;

SELECT column_name, column_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'r4';
+--------------+---------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  |  COLUMN_TYPE  |
+--------------+---------------+
| result       | double        |
| result2      | decimal(18,4) |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

> Will this somehow cause MySQL to do floating-point arithmetic?

I'd say you should refer to the SQL standard, but being MySQL, probably not the most reliable way of working out what will happen in practice :).

> how can I avoid [unexpected float casts]?

What I would do is explicitly the value(s) to be of a type that works for you:

```
SUM(A) / SUM(B) * CAST(100.0 AS DECIMAL(9,2))
```

unambiguous and helps with documentation for future-yous.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than debating the details of the calculation, format the result.  For example:

```
SELECT ROUND(100 * sum(...) / sum(...), 1) ...
```

That gives you the percent to one decimal place.

When you need "thousands separators" (not likely for percents), see the `FORMAT()` function.